# data sent from socket.io client unavailable at server socket to emit even tho emit event is registering

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I am running a node server on port 3000 and an angular app on port 4200.  I am attempting to send data through web sockets from the client to the server for the server. Sending data from the server to the client through web sockets is working.  The screenshot shows my angular CLI info on the node server next to a browser sending messages to the server.

The browser logs the information being sent to the server(chat.service.ts:22).  I join this array so that a string is sent to simplify things.(chat.service.ts:23)

The server receives socket.on('new-message') from the client, then logs the data received.  Unfortunately it's an empty string, noted by the blank space created by console.log(data). The word "string" comes from console.log(typeof(data))

I included the websocket.service.ts file but I'm not actually sure if it's relevant or if I'm even using it.  I am new to websockets and services in angular, and angular over all, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around how services work in angular.

Cheers,

[Image showing node server at localhost:3000 as well as client-side console output[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SEDp.png)

```
server.js:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
let socket = require('socket.io’);

// Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
let io = socket(server);

//Set Port
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
    socket.on('new-message', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('new-message', data);
        console.log(typeof(data));
    });
});
```

websocket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

    // Our socket connection
    private socket;

    constructor() { }

    connect(): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
        this.socket = io(localhost:3000);

        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
            this.socket.on('new-message', function(data){
                console.log("Received message from Websocket Server")
                observer.next(data);
            })
            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            }
        });
        // We define our Observer which will listen to messages

        let observer = {
            next: (data: Object) => {
                this.socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
            },
        };

        return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
    }

}
```

chat.service.ts:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

export class ChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
    private socket;
    result:any;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
    }

    public sendMessage(messageArray) {
        console.log('message array is now:')
        console.log(messageArray);
        this.socket.emit('new-message', messageArray.join('-'));
    }

    public loadPreviousMessages() {
        return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/messages")
          .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json().data));
      }

    public getMessages = () => {
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.socket.on('new-message', (messageArray) => {
                observer.next(messageArray);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, when you send a message in the client side you see  'message array is now:' with a non empty array, right ?

Comment: That's correct: chat.service.ts 22 outputs the array [handle: "John", Message:"Hey"]

Comment: strange format for an array, and the  messageArray.join('-') ?

Comment: using messageArray.join('_') seems to be the problem.  I can place:                   
(this.handle+"_"+this.message) into the "sendMessage" function with no problem, but I can't even console.log(messageArray.join('_')) without getting an empty string

Comment: Found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980004/join-associative-arrays-in-javascript  All makes sense now.

Comment: so it's ok you found the solution ? Your array was in fact an object, right ?

Comment: That is correct.  Trying to run .join on messageArray provided an undefined value as a result.  Learn something new every day.  I think I need to get an understanding of the difference between arrays and objects, and really how to identify which one I'm dealing with at any given time.